# How to set multiline,firstletter caps and disable suggestions on edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext for reply to email. i want to give three properties for edittext like Multiline, First character caps and disable word suggestions.
I gave like this in xml...

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textVisiblePassword"
```

I tried in code also...  etMessage.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
I am not able to give multiline....how can i achieve this

thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found solution for this problem

Just set the following parameters in xml file..

`android:inputType="textCapSentences|textVisiblePassword"`
These are for setting first letter of sentence to caps and disable suggestions

and write following code in ur Activity

```
edittext.setSingleLine(false);
```

Comment: Last code can also be done in XML: android:singleLine="false"

Comment: If you use textVisiblePassword, you loose the keyboard swipe option... You can do the same effect without the xxxxx like this: android:inputType="textCapSentences"

Answer (score 9):

Try setting `android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textVisiblePassword"`. What might be happening is that it is multiline but only one line is currently shown, in which you could say `android:minLines="5"` or so.

Comment: `android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"` works fine