# Disable suggestions in multiline EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, htcsense

How do you disable the autocorrection/autosuggestion features in a multilined EditText?

I tried:

[EditText without auto-correction, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799840/edittext-without-auto-correction-etc)

[Android: Multiline & No autosuggest in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653271/android-multiline-no-autosuggest-in-edittext)

[How can I turnoff suggestions in EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789905/how-to-turnoff-suggestions-in-edittext)

[How to set multiline,firstletter caps and disable suggestions on edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022581/how-to-set-multiline-firstletter-caps-and-disable-suggestions-on-edittext)

[How can I turnoff suggestions in EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789905/how-to-turnoff-suggestions-in-edittext)

None of the mentioned methods like "textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions" (in any combination) worked, neither declared in XML nor programmatically changed.
It seems that the EditText-box takes either multiline or turned-off suggestions, but not both at the same time.

I think it is important to know that I'm using the HTC Desire HD with Android 2.3.3. I don't have any other device to test this.

Is this behaviour inherent to the HTC Sense UI?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the Android vanilla keyboard or custom soft keyboard?

Comment: It's the vanilla keyboard from the Sense UI. Didn't change anything.
Just a note: It has the german locale.

Comment: I was just thinking the soft keyboard may not be respecting these parameters.

Comment: what if you turn off the Prediction setting - Settings->Language & Keyboard -> Touch Input -> Text Input -> Prediction. If works, try to disable this somehow in your app... I haven't tried it so far...

Comment: I'Ve tried this and it works. But I didn't find a way to change those settings programmatically yet...

Comment: just a suggestion - try to use the manifest feature android:configChanges="keyboard" and android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" :) good luck

Comment: Try this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21029

Answer (score 0):

The `inputType` tag that you specify in `EditText` for MultiLine and NoSuggestions are **flags** that can be **ignored** by the system depending on its preferences.

But, I can confirm that `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"` in the EditText XML works perfectly fine in Nexus and Motorola smartphones. So am guessing its due to your test device preferences that you are facing this problem.